# Problems with a menu and new activitys

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

i use the navigation drawer. There are a few menu items. When i press the item "news", the clicklistener opens a new activity. The user can press ten times the item "news" and ten times opens the same activity. How can i prevent that?

Comment: Why ten times??? Post some code

Comment: This is an example. The user touch the menu item and the clicklisterner calls the appropriate activity. If the user touch three times ... opens always the same activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag to check  if it's already open.
for example:

```
boolean activityIsOpen = false;
```

then on your menu click you check:

```
if (!activityIsOpen) {
  start your activity here
  activityIsOpen = true;
}
```

Now you have multiple ways to set the activityIsOpen back to false when you close your activity.
for example you can use:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    activityIsOpen = false;
    super.onResume();
}
```

or use startActivityForResult when calling your activity, and when you finish it, it will call this method on your menu activity:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    activityIsOpen = false;
}
```